# Use comma delimited string as input for variable in Bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I am trying to get some information from my heatpump, it puts out all of its settings in one long comma delimited string.
The string it outputs looks like this:

```
ret=OK,power=1,modus=4,adv=,temp1=21.0,humid=0,ds1=23.0,ds2=M,ds3=25.0,ds4=21.0,ds5=21.0
```

I would like to get these values into sperate variables so I can work with them in my bash script.
It has been too long since I wrote something in bash :( Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str='ret=OK,power=1,modus=4,adv=,temp1=21.0,humid=0,ds1=23.0,ds2=M,ds3=25.0,ds4=21.0,ds5=21.0'
IFS=, read -ra vars <<<"$str"
for v in "${vars[@]}"; do declare "$v"; done
```

Split the string on `,` into an array `vars`, then loop through the array using `declare` to perform the assignments.

A number of assumptions are made here. For example, there must be no space between the name of each variable and the value in your string. Also, it assumes that each of your variable names is valid.

Comment: This looks great, will try in a minute. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash
input='ret=OK,power=1,modus=4,adv=,temp1=21.0,humid=0,ds1=23.0,ds2=M,ds3=25.0,ds4=21.0,ds5=21.0'

input=${input//,/ [}
input='['${input//=/]=}
eval declare -A pump=($input)

echo ${pump[temp1]}
```

or, without `eval`:

```
input='ret=OK,power=1,modus=4,adv=,temp1=21.0,humid=0,ds1=23.0,ds2=M,ds3=25.0,ds4=21.0,ds5=21.0'

IFS=, read -a tuples <<< "$input"
declare -A pump
for tuple in "${tuples[@]}" ; do
    pump+=([${tuple%=*}]=${tuple#*=})
done

echo ${pump[temp1]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, going to try that now.